# Automatically accept all cookies in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Is it possible to set up Google Chrome browser to automatically accept all cookies without asking for permission? It can be annoying to consistently have to accept cookies when visiting new sites.

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to accept all cookies, as third-party cookies shouldn't be accepted and it's usually default behavior to block them. Third-party cookies are often used to track a user across all sites they visit _(it's been announced an update to Chrome this year will remove support for third-party cookies)_. Generally speaking, only strictly necessary cookies should be allowed, unless the user has a specific per site reason for allowing others.

Answer (score 0):

A required setting in Chrome for accepting all cookies:

- Click the three-line icon, then Settings
- Click Privacy and security
- In Third-party cookies, enable Allow third-party cookies.

The effect will be to allow third-party cookies. Primary site
cookies are always allowed by Chrome (unless you block them).

This is not enough to disable the prompts by websites for
accepting their cookies policies, so the use of a third-party
extension is required.

One such extension is
[I still don't care about cookies](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/i-still-dont-care-about-c/edibdbjcniadpccecjdfdjjppcpchdlm)
that has an excellent rating and is described as:

> This extension removes cookie warnings/pop-ups from almost all
> websites!
>
> The EU regulations require that any website using tracking cookies
> must get user's permission before installing them. Imagine how
> irritating that becomes when you surf anonymously or if you delete
> cookies automatically every time you close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **accept** everything automatically, that might not be too possible to achieve. There are extensions like [Accept all cookies](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/accept-all-cookies/ofpnikijgfhlmmjlpkfaifhhdonchhoi) that attempt this more or less, but you can see from reviews that there are bunch of complaints about their accuracy.

**Blocking** cookie popups without accepting, like the plugin from [@harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1825475/1145698) attempts to do, is easier both technically and because of how wide the support is in comparison, yet also far from perfect. For that I'd recommend using community updated lists for adblockers like [uBlock Origin](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm).

That extension has 2 lists uncluded in settings by default, which you can try out - **EasyList - Cookie Notices** and **uBlock filters – Cookie Notices**, that can also be used in other adblock extensions that support that format of filters. I've been using each for a while and they block ~99% of popups, unfortunately some of them are blocked in a way that makes using certain websites impossible as they mess up JS or leave an invisible element untouched, which blocks clicking anything on the site.

For more info about why it's so hard to cover automation of cookie notice/popup related actions, check [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1818757/on-chrome-how-to-change-cookie-setting-after-accept-all-for-a-site/1819471#1819471). TLDR: lack of standards for them.